# Write two vectors as convolution

Tags: fft, convolution

How to write two column vectors as an analytic convolution so that the discrete FFT may be used. MATLAB syntax is used.

Consider:

1. a set of vectors which, when sorted into a step function appears as any of the following:

   `[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]`, or `[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]`, or `[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]`

   (...the location at which the function "steps up" varies over members of this set)
2. The other is random `vec=[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]`, and obviously both contain only 0s and 1s.

Is it possible to write these vectors as an analytic convolution? I would like the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th... entries of the convolution to have values of:

```matlab
sum(vec.*[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
sum(vec.*[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0])
sum(vec.*[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])
sum(vec.*[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0])
... 
sum(vec.*[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
```

For speed, I am trying to avoid use of a for-loop. I cannot vectorize because this requires terabytes of RAM. (I work with vectors that are not of length 8, but rather length nearly a million).

The convolution theorem gives the function *R* from the convolution of functions *L* and *1/w* from the Fourier transform *F* and its inverse *F*<sup>-1</sup> as,

[image: <code>\[R(w) = \int {\frac{{L(w')}}{{w - w' + i{0^ + }}}dw'} = {F^{ - 1}}\left( {F\left( {L(w)} \right) \cdot F\left( {{\textstyle{1 \over w}}} \right)} \right)\]</code>]

Clearly, the function *1/(w-w')* in the convolution is from *1/w* under *F*; it's as if you just set *w'*=0. But if I use analogous reasoning in my `[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]`, I get either `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`, the identity under `.*` in MATLAB or `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`(a very boring result).

What is the mistake in reasoning I've made?

Comment: I think maybe you need to add some code to this, because I can't figure out what it is that you are trying to do. Yes, you can write any vector as a convolution of other vectors. What you describe with `sum(vector.*[...])` looks to be just `cumsum(vec)`, I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. I also don't understand how the vectors you show relate to *1/w*.

Comment: It turned out that cumsum was what I needed. It allowed me to speed up a calculation from requiring 15 minute to requiring under 10 seconds. Thank you!